# How can I create a rectangle with a border shadow in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have to create a rounded border with a shadow only on the border, 
like this:
[image]

I have tried to create a container with no background color, a rounded border and a BoxShadow like this:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
    boxShadow: [
      const BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        blurRadius: 2,
        offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: Text('text', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
),
```

The problem is that the shadow gets painted as if the rectangle was filled, so a solid shadow gets painted inside the rectangle, as you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

I also tried this, but I got the same result.

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    shadows: [
      const BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        blurRadius: 2,
        offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
      )
    ],
  ),
  child: Text('text', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
),
```

Is there a simple way I could achieve the desired effect? Or it is only possible with a custom painter?

Comment: it should be possible with custom `ShapeBorder` - see sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: @pskink thanks for the reply. But I don't think it would solve my problem. As you can see in the second code snippet, I tried `ShapeDecoration` with `RoundedRectangleBorder` as `ShapeBorder`. The problem is with the shadow though. I edited the post and included a screenshot of what the result is with my code.

Comment: @pskink I see, thank you! I'll try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `CustomPaint`

[image: 1]

```dart
Container(
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: MyPainter(),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Text('text', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30)),
    )
  ),
),
```

```dart
const double _kRadius = 10;
const double _kBorderWidth = 3;

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  MyPainter();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final rrectBorder = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(Offset.zero & size, Radius.circular(_kRadius));
    final rrectShadow = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(Offset(0, 3) & size, Radius.circular(_kRadius));

    final shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = _kBorderWidth
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 2);
    final borderPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = _kBorderWidth
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawRRect(rrectShadow, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawRRect(rrectBorder, borderPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```