# Flutter - How create this "message widget"?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created Flutter chat app. I use usually widget for message with BorderRadius. But now I need create this layout(customer requirement):

[image]

Please pay attention to the lower left corner. I do not know how to do that. 
Any ideas and tips. Is it possible on flutter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - ClipPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath)