# How to fill color inside a shape created using CustomPainter drawPath?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I've created a shape using drawPath and drawArc from CustomPainter, the PaintingStyle is stroke, but when I change it to fill, it only fills the arcs and not the whole shape. 
I want to fill the shape I created with a color, so how can I fill the shape with a particular color?

```
class CustomShapeCard extends CustomPainter {
  CustomShapeCard({@required this.strokeWidth, @required this.color});

  final double strokeWidth;
  final Color color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..color = color;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.2);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.9);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset((size.width * 0.2) - 14, size.height * 0.9),
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
      math.pi / 2,
      math.pi / 2,
      false,
      paint,
    );

    path.moveTo((size.width * 0.2) - 14, (size.height * 0.9) + 25);
    path.lineTo((size.width * 0.9) - 25, size.height * 0.9 + 25);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset((size.width * 0.9) - 25, size.height * 0.9),
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
      math.pi / 2,
      -math.pi / 2,
      false,
      paint,
    );

    path.moveTo((size.width * 0.9), (size.height * 0.9));
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.9, size.height * 0.35);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset((size.width * 0.9) - 25, size.height * 0.35),
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
      -math.pi / 2,
      math.pi / 2,
      false,
      paint,
    );

    path.moveTo((size.width * 0.9) - 25, (size.height * 0.35) - 25);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.25, (size.height * 0.35) - 25);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset((size.width * 0.25), (size.height * 0.35) - 50),
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
      math.pi / 2,
      math.pi / 3,
      false,
      paint,
    );

    path.moveTo((size.width * 0.25) - 20, (size.height * 0.35) - 35);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

When the PaintingStyle is stroke, I get this,

[image: PaintingStyle: Stroke]

When I change PaintingStyle to fill, I get,

[image: PaintingStyle: fill]

Comment: you dont need to draw all of those lines and arcs, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830 for more info

Comment: I'm trying it out currently, so no updates, I was going to reply once I was done trying it out

Comment: I got it using ClipPath, I didn't get it working with ShapeBorder though

Answer (score 0):

To fill a shape like this with a color,
the arcToPoint() should be used instead of drawArc().