# Drawing custom shapes in flutter

Tags: flutter, drawing, polygon, paint, shapes

I need to know all the different ways to make custom shapes. Like ***line, polygon, curve*** etc from points. I know, all these can be drawn using ***CustomPainter***, but sometime drawing simple line using a CustomPainter is a little bit over killed. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: check `ShapeDecoration` class documentation

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check that