# Add shadow to ClipPath created from Container - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, shadow, clip-path, flutter-widget

I want to add shadow to a ClipPath I have created from Container.
This is the ClipPath i created:

```
              ClipPath(
                clipper: RibbonClipper(),
                child: Container(
                  height: 20,
                  width: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    color: Color(0xFF338D5E),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

And CustomClipper Path is:

```
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * .90, size.height * .5);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot do that - use custom `ShapeBorder` instead

Answer (score 5):

I had to do that a while ago. I found [this very useful gist](https://gist.github.com/multiarts/6d732a5a99278ce359bbf16c005f7c85) that combines ClipPath and shadows. Alternatively, it seems like someone [made it a package](https://pub.dev/packages/clip_shadow), but I didn't test it.

Comment: no, no, no, if you want a custom shape use a custom `ShapeBorder` like any other flutters shapes (`BeveledRectangleBorder` / `CircleBorder` / `ContinuousRectangleBorder` / `RoundedRectangleBorder` / `StadiumBorder`), for a custom sample see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: Are you saying not to use ClipPath?? @pskink

Comment: @VijayPD You can try to use his method as it's less boilerplate (don't forget `clipBehaviour: Clip.antiAlias` on the `Container`). But I personally couldn't get it to work on my use case. It's not interchangeable like that with `ClipPath`. There's also a `ShapeBorderClipper` class which I can't find a good example of.