# How to draw a pointed triangle edge in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently creating a messaging app and I want to implement the following design.

[image]

How do I achieve the bottom triangular edge on left or right? I still learning `ClipPath` but I'm still having hard time understanding it. Thanks for the help

Comment: *"I still learning ClipPath but I'm still having hard time understanding it."* - do not use any `ClipPAth` - use `ShapeBorder` instead, something like  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: There is a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble) that will take over this task for you, I have used it before, it's good.

Comment: Solved it. And this is also a good package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble