# How to make a custom button shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-animation

I am working on a project and i want to achieve a  button [image: like this]

How can i easily make this shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use an image which represents this button and wrap it with `GestureDetector` (not recommended but sometimes the UI is so complex that making it purely in Flutter might be overkill, so keeping this option in mind is not bad) or play around with `CustomClipper`!

What you want to do is creating a `Container` or `FlatButton` and wrap it with `ClipPath` where you provide a `CustomClipper` as the `clipper` property of `ClipPath`. In your implementation of `CustomClipper` you shape the widget just ike you want it to. Check out this great Medium post (not written by me, credits go to Kinjal Dhamat) where she explains various ways how to use `CustomClipper` and shape everything you want:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-custom-clipper-28c6d380fdd6

As suggested by pskink, creating a custom `ShapeBorder` class, which will be set as the `shape` property of `FlatButton` for example, has quite some benefits but need some additional knowledge, take a look at this post:

[Flutter - ClipPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/)

Comment: `FlatButton` has `shape` property - no need for a custom clip

Comment: As far as I know if you want to make use of the `shape` property of `FlatButton`, you have to provide a `ShapeBorder` instance and since this is a custom shape you would have to extend `ShapeBorder` and implement the functions yourself and `ShapeBorder` has a lot of functions to implement - going the `CustomClipper` / `CustomPainter` way seems easier

Comment: in both cases you need a `Path` - return it from `getOuterPath` - that's all

Comment: Yes we need a `Path` in both cases, but as I wrote earlier, you still need to implement the other functions in `ShapeBorder` which are significantly more than in `CustomClipper` for example. But in the end both works just fine :)

Comment: *"you still need to implement the other functions in ShapeBorder which are significantly more than in CustomClipper for example. "* - i dont know what IDE you are using but both android studio and vs code do that in one mouse click - the `shape` property is in every button for some reason - if you want a circle button would you really add `CustomClipper` widget or simply `shape: CircleBorder()`? also `shape` property supports shape morphing - try for example `CircleBorder` and after calling `setState` change it to `RoundedRectangleBorder` and you will see "magical" shape morphing

Comment: For simple use cases like a circle using `CircleBorder` is the choice, no doubt! But I just tried extending `ShapeBorder` and I have to override 5 functions (`dimensions`, `getOuterPath`, `getInnerPath`, `paint`, `scale`), `getOuterPath` and `getInnerPath` both should not share the same Path for a given rect (at least according to the documentation) and I have to write the `paint` functions additionally, so on the first look it seems like a lot more effort than writing a `CustomClipper` or what do you say?

Comment: no: you need only `getOuterPath` nothing more, (if you want a custom placement for your child widget override `dimensions`, if you want some extra painting override `paint`) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830 and now try https://pastebin.com/raw/YL94bNYh, dont you really think that this clipping is a cheap workaround? you have no child placing, no shadows, no shape morphing, no custom painting, nothing, just brute clipping

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, seems like extending `ShapeBorder` has nice benefits! Creating `ShapeBorder` involves knowing all this stuff first, using `CustomClipper` is easier since you have 2 methods to override where 1 of them just wants to know if it should be repainted. At the end it's case dependent if there is even a difference, when using morphing or shadow absolutely!

Comment: and here is the proof https://pastebin.com/vZgnce5q that only one method is really needed - check `MyShapeBorder` class, btw did you notice that `ClipPath` does not work with `FlatButton` (because of top/bottom padding)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html). Have a look at [this great example](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-in-flutter-aa197bda94bf) on how to use this.

Here is a small example of what you want to achieve (though I didn't do the rounded border but you can easily expand:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Drawing Paths',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print('Do Something'),
            child: CustomPaint(
              size: Size(200, 50),
              painter: CurvePainter(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xFFE32087)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width*0.2, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height*0.2)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**The result**:

[image: Button image]