# How to create this rounded offset rectangle in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create this shape but am struggling. Have tried using shape maker but am struggling also to make this shape. I also tried using path, but am unsure whether this will work.

Any suggestions?

[what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf0yK.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a custom button shape in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534487/how-to-make-a-custom-button-shape-in-flutter)

Comment: yeah, thanks was just looking for some inspiration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of  `CustomPainter`  we can draw  any kind of custom button and container, Flutter gives you access to low-level graphics painting. Best of all, painting in Flutter is fast and efficient.

`CustomPaint` takes a `painter` argument of type `CustomPainter`, an `abstract class` from the `Flutter APIs`.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  child: CustomPaint(painter: FaceOutlinePainter()),
),
```

and in `FaceOutlinePainter()` class you can add the size , width  , height and all other requirment.

```
class FaceOutlinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: draw something with canvas
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FaceOutlinePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKgtKxRLX4
I've used this few times and it worked pretty well