# How to make custom design button Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement this UI design as shown in the attached image. However, I have not been successful in creating something that looks and feel like the one shown in the attached image. Below is what I have been trying my hands on:

```
                         ElevatedButton(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text("A:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color: Colors.yellowAccent)),
                                Spacer(),
                                Text("Butterfly",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.yellowAccent,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                Spacer(),
                              ],),
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              shape: StadiumBorder(),
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){

                            },
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text("B:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color: Colors.yellowAccent)),
                                Spacer(),
                                Text("Ant",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.yellowAccent,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                Spacer(),
                              ],),
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              shape: StadiumBorder(),
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){

                            },
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text("C:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color: Colors.yellowAccent)),
                                Spacer(),
                                Text("Scorpion",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.yellowAccent,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                Spacer(),
                              ],),
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              shape: StadiumBorder(),
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){

                            },
                          ),

                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text("D:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color: Colors.yellowAccent)),
                                Spacer(),
                                Text("Bee",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.yellowAccent,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                Spacer(),
                              ],),
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              shape: StadiumBorder(),
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){

                            },
                          ),
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers/versions/1.1.2 try this package

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534487/how-to-make-a-custom-button-shape-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

If you have an svg image of the shape you want you can convert it to a CustomPaint object that you can use as the background of the button using this converter: https://fluttershapemaker.com/

Comment: this is GOLD :)

Comment: Isn't it awesome? Why waste hours trying to make your own custom painter when it can just do it in 2 seconds XD