# how to draw this button in flutter using clipPath?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

**Good Morning**

> Please How to Draw button like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WYNs.png) in flutter ?
> after search i found i will use clipathi tried it more than times but i failed to do it so how to draw it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Before creating any `CustomClipper`, I would highly recommend you to first draw it on a piece of paper & try to understand exactly what you want to do.

[image: Clipper]

Mark approximate co-ordinates as I have done like `0.7` on X-axis & `0.3` on Y-axis.

Then try to think how should we move the clipper so that we can create the following shape.

Steps:

1. Move to `(size.width, 0)`
2. Make a line to `(size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.3)`
3. Draw a bezier curve to `(size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.7)` with control point as `(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.5)`
4. Make a line to `(size.width, size.height)`
5. Close our path by making a line to `(size.width, 0)`.

So, create your `CustomClipper` with the above steps:

Here is the final result:
[image: Result]

Here is the implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Placeholder(),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            'Heading',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 24,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            'Description',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ClipPath(
          clipper: MyClipper(),
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Colors.indigo,
            child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
            height: 150,
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Text(
              'Next',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        ),),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.5, size.width * 0.7,
        size.height * 0.7);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer, I was almost done with my code, but your example and explanation are far better than what I would have posted.

Comment: no, no, no - `ClipPath` is not a good way of creating custom raised buttons - instead use `shape` property - the docs say: *"The shape of the button's Material.

The button's highlight and splash are clipped to this shape. If the button has an elevation, then its drop shadow is defined by this shape as well.

Defaults to the value from the current ButtonTheme, ButtonThemeData.shape."*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate? For a custom shape like this, I think using `ClipPath` is okay. Can you show how to achieve this custom shape using the `shape` property of button?

Comment: Also, the question itself asks for creating the button using `ClipPath`. So, I guess my solution answers the question. A comment would be appreciated but giving a downvote is a little too much.

Comment: *"Can you show how to achieve this custom shape using the shape property of button? "* - like any other existing `ShapeBorder` classes - see sources of `CircleBorder` / `ContinuousRectangleBorder` / `RoundedRectangleBorder` - for example for a circular button use `shape: CircleBorder()`

Comment: and the fact that OP asks for a `ClipPath` does not mean that he should use that bad workaround if there is a `shape` property designed for such case

Comment: For a custom border like the one mentioned in the question above, I don't think `CircleBorder`/`ContinuousRectangleBorder`/`RoundedRectangleBorder`/`BeveledRectangleBorder` will work. That's why we had to create a `CustomClipper`.

Comment: I have tried using `shape` property & `BeveledRectangleBorder`, but the final result is not the same as the one above.

Comment: *"That's why we had to create a CustomClipper"* - not at all: you need a custom `ShapeBorder` - something like this: `class MyShape extends ShapeBorder { ...` - i said to look into `CircleBorder/ContinuousRectangleBorder/RoundedRectangleBorder/BeveledRectangleBorder` since they are just examples of existing implementations, if it is still unclear, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: Hello
You made a great answer and great explanation thanks for your efforts that's what i was needed
But i found magic tool that made what u did it's allow u to sketch ur shape and automatically generate ur code
U can give it a try and u can watch it's tutorial video at https://fluttershapemaker.com/

Comment: Okay, @pskink. I will give it a try.