# How can I add shadow to custom painted widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I drew triangle with custom painter, and I want to add shadow to it.

```
class TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color strokeColor;
  final PaintingStyle paintingStyle;
  final double strokeWidth;

  TrianglePainter({this.strokeColor = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 3, this.paintingStyle = PaintingStyle.stroke});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = strokeColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = paintingStyle;

    canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  Path getTrianglePath(double x, double y) {
    return Path()
        ..moveTo(x*(1-sqrt(3)/4)/2+x/15, y/4)
        ..lineTo(x*(1-sqrt(3)/4)/2+x/15, y*3/4)
        ..lineTo(x*(1+sqrt(3)/4)/2+x/15, y/2)
        ..lineTo(x*(1-sqrt(3)/4)/2+x/15, y/4);
    
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TrianglePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.strokeColor != strokeColor ||
        oldDelegate.paintingStyle != paintingStyle ||
        oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth;
  }
  
}
```

above is the triangle painter code.

so how can I add shadow to it?
or is there any way to draw triangle with container?
and I hope I can customize shadow's x, y, blur, and spread values.
Thank you for reading, and I'll wait for your advice :)

Comment: use custom `ShapeBorder` not `CustomPaint` - more https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: [Use Custom Shape Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath/57943257#57943257) Here is example

Comment: how can I change that above code with shape border... can't find the way to use rect.....

Comment: in the code above, x = size.width, and y=size.height. To change that code to Shape Border, will substituting rect.topLeft for x, rect.bottomRight for y work?

Comment: @pskink pls help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use, this universal custom `ShapeBorder`

```
class ShapeBuilder extends ShapeBorder {
  final Path Function(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) pathBuilder;

  ShapeBuilder(this.pathBuilder);

  @override EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => null;
  @override Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;
  @override void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;
  @override ShapeBorder scale(double t) => null;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => pathBuilder(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
}
```

now, with the following "builder" fuction:

```
Path trangle(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
  return Path()
    ..moveTo(rect.topCenter.dx, rect.topCenter.dy)
    ..lineTo(rect.bottomRight.dx, rect.bottomRight.dy)
    ..lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx, rect.bottomLeft.dy);
}
```

you can use it like:

```
Container(
  width: 64,
  height: 64,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    shape: ShapeBuilder(trangle),
    shadows: [
      BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 4.0, offset: Offset(2, 2)),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: lib/main.dart:139:35: Error: Type 'ui.TextDirection' not found.
  final Path Function(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection textDirection}) pathBuilder;
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I'm nearly new to flutter..sorry

Comment: your welcome, of course it is up to you what you return from `triangle` builder function - i just used the most simple form