# How to make custom shape with black solid rounded border using ShapeBorder Class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, border, customization, shapes

I want to have this mentioned below shape in flutter with black solid borders around it, I am new to flutter and I do not know much about ShapeBorder to create this kind of shape , please help me out, how to create this by using ShapeBorder, I have written some code below but it does not have any black border around it? please help me out, thanks in advance,

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class InfoDialog extends ShapeBorder {
      final bool usePadding;
    
      InfoDialog({this.usePadding = true});
    
      @override
      EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only(bottom: usePadding? 20 : 0);
    
      @override
      Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;
    
      @override
      Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
        rect = Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, 13));
        return Path()
          ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(5)))
          ..moveTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx+40 , rect.bottomCenter.dy)
          ..relativeLineTo(5, 10)
          ..relativeLineTo(10, -10)
          ..close();
      }
    

      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {


    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    canvas.drawPath(getOuterPath(rect), paint);
}
    
      @override
      ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
    }
```

This is my output and want to make like second one

[image]

This is what I want to make, please look into it

[image: enter code here]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830

Comment: bro I have tried that but as I am new to flutter so I could not make it out, edit because I do not know about CustomPainter please assist me to create mentioned shape

Comment: in the link i posted no `CustomPainter` is used - instead it creates a custom `ShapeBorder` and produces shape like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDXMA.png)

Comment: I do not even know about custom ShapeBorder class as a newbie, It would be so kind of you guys if you help me out creating this shape with rounded black border

Comment: did you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

[image: snapshot]

```
Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
rect = Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, 13));
Path p1 = Path()
  ..moveTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx + 40, rect.bottomCenter.dy)
  ..relativeLineTo(5, 10)
  ..relativeLineTo(10, -10)
  ..close();

Path p2 = Path()
  ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(5)))
  ..close();

return Path.combine(PathOperation.union, p1, p2);}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see this example and you can use flutter_custom_clippers: ^1.1.2 and easily make like this. example:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers/example

Comment: I already have explored this package but did not work for me please if it is possible customize above code or your code to make this exact shape I will be obliged to you, thanks

Comment: can i see your code? so i can understand proper needs.

Comment: I have uploaded my code above and desired shape below, code is working and making custom shape but not as I want , I have uploaded custom shape as well which got created from my code ,you can see above , there are two shapes above first one is the result of my code and second one is the desired shape which I want to make