# How to draw the pin on path with CustomClipper in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, custom-painting

How I can draw this **pin** on the `path` while using `CustomClipper`?

```dart
class ErrorClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  ErrorClipper({
    this.radius = 5,
    this.offset = 10,
    this.nipSize = 10,
  });

  final double radius;
  final double offset;
  final double nipSize;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBR(
          nipSize,
          0,
          size.width,
          size.height,
          Radius.circular(radius),
        ),
      );

/// I can create the pin on the left side
    // final path2 = Path()
    //   ..lineTo(0, 2 * nipSize)
    //   ..lineTo(-nipSize, nipSize)
    //   ..lineTo(0, 0);
    //
    // path.addPath(path2, Offset(nipSize, size.height/2.7));
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Usage of **ErrorClipper**

```dart
PhysicalShape(
                  clipper: ErrorClipper(
                    errorBubbleType: ErrorBubbleType.leftEdge,
                  ),
                  elevation: 2,
                  color: theme.primaryColor,
                  shadowColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 4, 16, 8),
                    child: Text(
                      context.l10n.pictureMissingError,
                      style: theme.textTheme.bodyText2,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

**ExpectedResult:**
[image: Expected result]

**Currently achieved:**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath/57943257#57943257

Comment: How you are using it , can you include the way you have tested it?

Comment: @pskink I have tried, but not getting how to invert the pin to the top

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, I have tried and tested.

Comment: Can you include where you've used `ErrorClipper` and how you are showing it?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Updated the question with usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am moving the path first, then drawing the path,

Change the second path like

```dart
    final path2 = Path()
      ..moveTo(nipSize * 2, 0)
      ..lineTo(nipSize * 3, -nipSize)
      ..lineTo(nipSize * 4, 0);

    path.addPath(path2, Offset.zero);
```

[image]