# How to add arrow at bottom of a message box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Please help me on how can I create this box

[message box to be created in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIYCm.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - ClipPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath)

Answer (score 0):

you ca use these packages to have a bubble shape for a message

bubble: ^1.2.1
flutter_chat_bubble: ^2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

you can use [customPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) or [CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) , in this case, better use clipper because we need all size from its child,

code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MessageBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const MessageBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MessageBoxState createState() => _MessageBoxState();
}

class _MessageBoxState extends State<MessageBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 200,),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0)
            ),
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: MessageClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 20,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    
    var firstOffset = Offset(size.width * 0.1, 0.0);
    var secondPoint = Offset(size.width * 0.15, size.height );
    var lastPoint = Offset(size.width * 0.2, 0.0);
    var path = Path()
    ..moveTo(firstOffset.dx, firstOffset.dy)
    ..lineTo(secondPoint.dx, secondPoint.dy)
    ..lineTo(lastPoint.dx, lastPoint.dy)
    ..close();


    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
   
    return true;
  }

}
```

here result :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the bubble from material design by importing

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

or simply :-

```
    Bubble(
  margin: BubbleEdges.only(leftBottom: 10),
  nip: BubbleNip.rightTop,
  color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 255, 199, 1.0),
  child: Text('Your Text', textAlign: TextAlign.right)
```

If u need more reference [read this](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble).

Comment: `Bubble` is not from material design and requires the user to import a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble).