# Custom Textbutton shape

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to achieve `Textbutton` shape like this image
[image]

I've tried this

```dart
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<BeveledRectangleBorder>(
          BeveledRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      )),
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
    ),
    child: Text('')),
```

Comment: Can you update the question of what you've tried so far. You can use `ClipPath` for shape.

Comment: TextButton(onPressed: (){},
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<BeveledRectangleBorder>(
                          BeveledRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          )
                      ),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
                  ),
                        child: Text('')),

Comment: Can you include this comment on question?

Comment: This is more like  [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) widget.

Comment: yes like stepper but i need to shape like this

Comment: basically its the buttons when user press on one of them the status of the client changes

Comment: You can use Container with custom border on step. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

Use this package make some changes and wrap with InkWell https://pub.dev/packages/shape_of_view_null_safe