# How to fit the text inside a specific area of custom clipPath

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-clippath

I have created this UI
[image]

the problem is right now that the text is not displayed fully. How can i put the text for example inside the upper part of the ui so that the text is not covered by the clipped area of the ui, so that it can ignore somehow the bottom part of the ui where i have marked as red container in this picture

[image]

**this is my complete code**

```dart
class QuoteWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuoteWidget({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: AppCustomClipPath(
        shadow: Shadow(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), //color of shadow
          blurRadius: 15, // blur radius
          offset: const Offset(0, 2),
        ),
        clipper: CustomQuotePainter(),
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 60,
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
          ),
          child: Text(
            "Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum  Lorem Impsum Lorem    Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem       Impsum",
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .displaySmall!
                .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomQuotePainter extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.0001600, size.height * 0.0004800);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 1.0015800, size.height * -0.0002800);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 1.0015800, size.height * 0.6996800);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.4008200, size.height * 0.7007400);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.2009700, size.height * 0.9068600);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.2006800, size.height * 0.6992200);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * -0.0002100, size.height * 0.7003800);
    path0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0001600, size.height * 0.0004800);
    path0.close();

    return path0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

@immutable
class AppCustomClipPath extends StatelessWidget {
  final Shadow? shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path>? clipper;
  final Widget? child;

  const AppCustomClipPath({
    super.key,
    @required this.shadow,
    @required this.clipper,
    @required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      painter: _ClipShadowShadowPainter(
        clipper: clipper!,
        shadow: shadow!,
      ),
      child: ClipPath(child: child, clipper: this.clipper),
    );
  }
}

class _ClipShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Shadow? shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path>? clipper;

  _ClipShadowPainter({@required this.shadow, @required this.clipper});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = shadow!.toPaint();
    var clipPath = clipper!.getClip(size).shift(shadow!.offset);
    canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: you need a custom `ShapeBorder` not `CustomClipper` - shape border has `dimensions` property you should override

Comment: Would you please give me some more informations how to achieve the same by using the ShapeBorder?

Comment: Also it seems path needed some modification, not getting the use of those fraction values

Comment: ok and how would i do this i mean what should be changed in order to acieve the desired ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `ShapeBorder`

```dart
class CustomShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions =>
      EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 9, bottom: 20, top: 8); //todo

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.addRect(rect);
    Path bottomCurve = Path()
      ..moveTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx + rect.width * .2, rect.bottom)
      ..lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx + rect.width * .2, rect.bottom + 40)
      ..lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx + rect.width * .2 + 80, rect.bottom);

    path0.close();
    return Path.combine(PathOperation.union, path0, bottomCurve);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return getInnerPath(rect);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

And use it like

```dart
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  ),
  decoration:
      ShapeDecoration(shape: CustomShapeBorder(), color: Colors.green),
  child: Text(
    "Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum  Lorem Impsum Lorem    Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem Impsum Lorem       Impsum",
    style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .displaySmall!
        .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
  ),
),
```

Comment: there is a better answer by pskink, If i found it, I will attach

Comment: probably it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath#57943257

Comment: yap, this is the one

Comment: Guyes you are just awsome. Thank you sooo much you have saved my time digging through the problem. It worked like magic and the result is exactly what i wanted